# Компилируемая программа с GUI в pyinstaller, не запускается

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyqt5, pyinstaller

команда:

```
pyinstaller -F "C:\for cheacher\sentense.py"
```

ход выполнения работы:

```
123 INFO: PyInstaller: 3.5
132 INFO: Python: 3.7.3
136 INFO: Platform: Windows-10-10.0.18362-SP0
138 INFO: wrote C:\for cheacher\sentense.spec
140 INFO: UPX is not available.
151 INFO: Extending PYTHONPATH with paths
['C:\\for cheacher', 'C:\\for cheacher']
152 INFO: checking Analysis
153 INFO: Building Analysis because Analysis-00.toc is non existent
154 INFO: Initializing module dependency graph...
157 INFO: Initializing module graph hooks...
165 INFO: Analyzing base_library.zip ...
6393 INFO: running Analysis Analysis-00.toc
6397 INFO: Adding Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls to dependent assemblies of final executable
  required by c:\users\danila\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python.exe
7330 INFO: Caching module hooks...
7350 INFO: Analyzing C:\for cheacher\sentense.py
7420 INFO: Loading module hooks...
7420 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-encodings.py"...
7642 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-pydoc.py"...
7646 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.py"...
7889 WARNING: Hidden import "sip" not found!
7894 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtCore.py"...
8414 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtGui.py"...
9077 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-PyQt5.QtWidgets.py"...
10282 INFO: Loading module hook "hook-xml.py"...
10777 INFO: Looking for ctypes DLLs
10777 INFO: Analyzing run-time hooks ...
10782 INFO: Including run-time hook 'pyi_rth_pyqt5.py'
10794 INFO: Looking for dynamic libraries
20006 INFO: Looking for eggs
20008 INFO: Using Python library c:\users\danila\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\python37.dll
20010 INFO: Found binding redirects:
[]
20031 INFO: Warnings written to C:\for cheacher\build\sentense\warn-sentense.txt
20118 INFO: Graph cross-reference written to C:\for cheacher\build\sentense\xref-sentense.html
20148 INFO: checking PYZ
20148 INFO: Building PYZ because PYZ-00.toc is non existent
20150 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\for cheacher\build\sentense\PYZ-00.pyz
21329 INFO: Building PYZ (ZlibArchive) C:\for cheacher\build\sentense\PYZ-00.pyz completed successfully.
21346 INFO: checking PKG
21346 INFO: Building PKG because PKG-00.toc is non existent
21347 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg
21632 WARNING: One binary added with two internal names.
21636 WARNING: ('libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\danila\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
21637 WARNING: was placed previously at
21637 WARNING: ('PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'C:\\users\\danila\\appdata\\local\\programs\\python\\python37-32\\lib\\site-packages\\PyQt5\\Qt\\bin\\libGLESv2.dll',
 'BINARY')
35635 INFO: Building PKG (CArchive) PKG-00.pkg completed successfully.
35648 INFO: Bootloader c:\users\danila\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\bootloader\Windows-32bit\run.exe
35649 INFO: checking EXE
35649 INFO: Building EXE because EXE-00.toc is non existent
35649 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc
35650 INFO: Appending archive to EXE C:\for cheacher\dist\sentense.exe
35715 INFO: Building EXE from EXE-00.toc completed successfully.
```

вот ошибка:

```
    Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "sentense.py", line 1, in <module>
    from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets
  File "c:\users\danila\appdata\local\programs\python\python37-32\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py", line 41, in <module>
  File "site-packages\PyQt5\__init__.py", line 33, in find_qt
ImportError: unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH
[2624] Failed to execute script sentense
```

Comment: `unable to find Qt5Core.dll on PATH` в PATH укажите путь к данной либе

Comment: Я хочу выпустить это программу а небольшой свет. Где можно найти этот файл и как автоматически добавлять в PATH?

Comment: @5478512, в папке питона поищите по имени. После зайдите в переменные пути и в переменную PATH добавьте путь к **папке** с той dll

Answer (score 0):

Если ничего не работает, попробуйте переустановить PyInstaller:
pip install https://github.com/pyinstaller/pyinstaller/archive/develop.tar.gz

Answer (score 0):

Возможно, вы напутали с виртуальным окружением. Если вы работаете с виртуальным окружением, например, в pycharm, pyinstaller не может найти библиотеку, т. к запускается без venv.
У меня была похожая проблема